# StorageTek SL500 Serial Number from Netbackup

Tags: tape, netbackup

I have a Sun StorageTek SL500 tape library that I need to put in a service call, but don't have the serial number handy.  Does anyone know if it is possible to get the serial number for the library from netbackup or the Linux host which the library is attached too?

Comment: Does the answer by @Kamy work for you? If it works you should upvote and/or accept it. If it does not work for you, a comment on that answer explaining why it didn't work for you would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the udev package is installed, then

```
# /lib/udev/scsi_id  --page=0x80   --whitelisted      /dev/sg4
SSPECTRA PYTHON         0123456456
```

where 0123456456 is the Serial Number